# How to emulate a HTML multiselect of inputs in Ruby tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can you input multiple values for the one field into a Ruby functional test, much like a multiselect box?  Code below that I thought would work, doesn't.

```
post :create, :post => { :multiselect1 => ['value1', 'value2'] , :multiselect2 => ['value3', 'value4'] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you were really trying to post `"post[multiselect1][]"` and `"post[multiselect2][]"` you should try this:

```
post :create, {:multiselect1 => ['value1', 'value2'] , :multiselect2 => ['value3', 'value4'] }
```

this will submit `"multiselect1[]"` and `"multiselect2[]"`

let me know if my assumption was wrong

cheers!

Comment: Thanks Addy!  Your assumptions are correct.  But it seems that the multiselects built with the collection_select() form helper actually send posts off in the format multiselect1[another_value][post_value_here]. Is there any way to emulate this in a functional test input?

Comment: Thats correct. what is the model that you are trying to use? is the model name "Post"?